# Oracle fuzzy searching with UTL functions

Tags: sql, oracle, fuzzy-search, edit-distance, jaro-winkler

I need to implement fuzzy search on database layer, but I am having some minor issues. Here is my SQL code for demonstration :

```
SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT *
   FROM TOOLS 
   WHERE UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(UPPER('sample tool'), UPPER(NAME)) > 80
   ORDER BY UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY('sample tool', NAME) DESC)
   where ROWNUM <= 10;
```

I am selecting 10 tools that match best the criteria of **jaro winkler and edit distance similarity** utl functions. Struggle I am having is, that I am not getting exact matches first. For example when I type rich the best scored candidate is **'mich'** and then are tools with name **'rich'** for example **'rich 12'**, **'rich ax'**, ...

1. Is it possible to get **"exact matches"** first with these utl functions or is there any function that fits my requirements better? Our fuzzy search should be **focused more on skipping** some characters rather than replacing them for another.
2. Is it possible to not take into account **word length** with these functions? (for example when I type 'di' I want to get results as 'dinosaur', but the word doesn't match my score criteria only because its length and I am getting no results.

Answer (score 1):

Rank results first, fetch the ones with the highest rank. Something like this (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  tools (name) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select 'mich' from dual union all
  5     select 'rich 12' from dual union all
  6     select 'rich ax' from dual
  7    ),
  8  temp as
  9    -- rank similirities first
 10    (select name,
 11         utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity('&&par_tool', name) sim,
 12         --
 13         rank() over (order by
 14           utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity('&&par_tool', name) desc) rnk
 15     from tools
 16    )
 17  -- finally, return the "top" similar values
 18  select name, sim, rnk
 19  from temp
 20  where rnk = 1;
Enter value for par_tool: rich

NAME              SIM        RNK
---------- ---------- ----------
rich 12            91          1
rich ax            91          1

SQL> undefine par_tool
SQL> /
Enter value for par_tool: mick

NAME              SIM        RNK
---------- ---------- ----------
mich               88          1

SQL>
```